# FORM_TAG (Rails): how to add selected to an option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, selected

I've a "form_tag" form in rails.

Now I've the problem, that I'm loading some options from my DB to a select tag.

```
<%= select("get", "object_id", Object.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id, {:'data-email' => p.email}] }) %>
```

I've the ID of the object I want to get selected in another variable @object.id

(normally, I solve that with collection_select. But that's not working together with "form_tag" as far as I can see - only with "form_for")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

> By default, post.person_id is the selected option. Specify :selected => value to use a different selection or :selected => nil to leave all options unselected.

```
select("get", "object_id", Object.all.collect {|p| [p.name, p.id, {:'data-email' => p.email}] }, { :selected => @object.id })
```

Comment: Thanks for your very fast help! I tried something similar to that solution - but I think my problem was, I had the ":prompt => "Some text"" included, too...